# How to get device prompt via SSH using Paramiko?

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, prompt, paramiko

I want to read off the hostname of a router from its CLI prompt when I SSH into it using Paramiko but I'm just getting a blank output using the code below.

```
import paramiko, socket

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(router, username=abc, password=abc, timeout=5)

ssh = ssh.invoke_shell()
output = ssh.recv(1000)
print output
```

Command-line prompt of router that I want to receive:

```
Router#
```